# Quadric in $\mathbb{P}^3(k)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

i'm trying to work my way through Perrin's algebraic geometry introduction and i'm struggling on this :

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. We can show that any quadric of $\mathbb{P}^3(k)$ is of the form $Q=V(XT-YZ)$. Show that $Q$ contains two families of lines that we index by $\mathbb{P}^1(k)$, and that by every point of $Q$ passes a unique line of every family. Then show that two lines of the same family are disjoint and that two lines of different family intersect in one point.

What i tried is this,

We take a point in $k^4$ of homogenous coordinates $(x,y,z,t)$ that verifies $xt-yz=0$.

We let $t=1$, then we get the equation $x=yz$.

By setting $y=\alpha \in k$, we get, $ x=\alpha z $.

Now if i set $z=0$ we get a point $(0,\alpha,0,1)$ which is a first point.
If $z=1$ we get another on which is $(\alpha,\alpha,1,1)$.

I took the plane $\Lambda=Vect((0,\alpha,0,1),(\alpha,\alpha,1,1))$ for $\alpha \in k$.

If i'm not mistaken it will correspond to a projective line in the projective space of the form $\{ \mu(0,\alpha,0,1)+ \lambda(\alpha,\alpha,1,1) |  \mu,\lambda \in k\}= \{(\lambda \alpha,\alpha (\mu+\lambda),\lambda,\mu + \lambda) |\lambda, \mu \in k\}$.

We can that see that any element of that form verifies the defining equation of $Q$.

Now i think i have to homogenize the equations i had for $x$ and $y$ by letting $y=\alpha t$ for $t$ non zero in $k$. This should be not far from what we want but we need to get back the point at infinity.

So we can say that $\alpha=\frac{u}{v}$ and get $vy=ut$ and another equation using $x=\alpha z$ which becomes $vx=uz$.

I think the point of homogenous coordinates that verifies those two equations gives us the first family of line in  $\mathbb{P}^3(k)$ indexed by $\mathbb{P}^1(k)$ as any point $(u,v) \in \mathbb{P}^1(k)$ verifying $vx=uz$ and $vy=ut$ verifies the defining equation of $Q$.

This is only the first part but am i making sense or did i misunderstand anything ?

Thank you for your help.